# Make multiple apps report as the same app

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android

I have an app which is sold as a whitelabel product.  The apps are identical, even down to version number.  The only difference is some assets.  I would like all of these apps to report to Crashlytics as if they were my main app, so all my stats are in one place.  Any idea how to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Crashlytics doesn't support rolling-up crash data for multiple apps but I'll bring this request back to the team.

Comment: Thanks for looking at it.  I understand its kind of a corner case, but I expect we aren't quite the only people who would benefit from it.

Comment: Yeah, I've heard a few developers with apps having shared codebases request this. Definitely our our radar as a possible enhancement.

Comment: The company I work for also has a single codebase that gets deployed as multiple "branded" apps in the App Store (i.e. OurHighSchoolApp, AnotherHighSchoolApp, etc.)  Like Gabe's app, the only difference is some image assets. I agree it would be nice to get a consolidated report of crashes and daily active users.

Comment: We are in the same boat. We have hundreds of apps (over 800 as of now) which are all exactly the same, but with different assets. It is impractical to create 800 apps or 800 projects.